# What does 'NVP' mean in the context of C++ / serialization?

Tags: c++, serialization, cereal

The C++ serialization library [cereal](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_archives.html) uses the acronym NVP several times in its documentation without mentioning what it means.

A quick web search brings up further hits related to boost serialization, and on first glance I couldn't spot a full spelling of the acronym either. It seems to be some kind of C++ serialization related slang.

What does it stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "Name Value Pair".

KVP (Key-Value Pair) is another common acronym for the same concept you may have run into. They are interchangeable.

> It seems to be some kind of C++ serialization related slang.

Not really. It's an acronym specific to `boost::serialization`. As far as I can tell, cereal inherited it out of its explicit positioning as an alternative to that original library.

Comment: And here's an example of boost docs using this term: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html

Comment: The cereal documentation also uses the full term here: https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/assets/doxygen/group__Utility.html#ga78892c2ccfac7a5454639ca121e84439